# How to load an image to an imageView if a radio button is selected

Tags: android, imageview, radio-button

Hi I'm doing a school project and I'm doing a gender classification. If I select male, a male icon should load to the imageView and Vice Versa in my android app.

```
public static TextView lable5,lable7;
public static SeekBar SB1,SB2;
public static RadioButton RB1,RB2;
public static ImageView IV1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

    lable5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5); //this is for seekbar1
    lable7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7); //This is for seekbar2
    RB1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1); // This is for male option
    RB2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2); // This is for Female Option
    IV1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView); // This is the only imageView available


    SB1=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);// This is for seekBar1
    SB2=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);//This is for seekBar2
    lable5.setText(String.valueOf(SB1.getProgress()));
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read about [how to ask a good question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And note: Java and JavaScript are separate languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you added the radio buttons in a `RadioGroup` you can do the following:

```
group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    switch(checkedId) {
      case R.id.radioButton1:
        IV1.setImageResource(R.drawable.male_icon);
        break;
      case R.id.radioButton2:
        IV1.setImageResource(R.drawable.female_icon);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

In case that your radio buttons aren't in `RadioGroup` you can add them with a code like this:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup" >
    <RadioButton ... />
    <RadioButton ... />
</RadioGroup>
```

In case that you have problems using my code, please post a comment and I will help you.

Comment: It was in the radio group and i'm getting an error saying int can't be converted to Drawable

Comment: My bad. Sorry about that! I updated the answer and it should work right now. The problem was that I used `setImageDrawable` which has a `Drawable` parameter and I was sending an `int`. Using `setImageResource` you can set an image by its id.

Comment: Thank you It's working fab :D

Comment: i have a radio button, 2 text fields and a seekbar input can help me reading them in to the float variables pleaseee ??

Comment: I can't understand what's the problem. Can you please give some more details?

Comment: Right now i went to this extent my idea is to get the inputs from textfields and seekbar textview as an input to the variables in cal1z() metheod go through this java file once and tell me where i have done mistake           https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B85itaiU-shzXzVlWVJZQk9pN3M/view?usp=sharing     pleaseee

Comment: and i want it as integers only to compare in the if condition